# How do I get my IIS web app to authenticate intranet users using a FQDN?

Tags: active-directory, iis, asp.net

I am maintaining a web application that runs using Windows authentication on IIS and serves a campus intranet. A domain administrator has issued me an SSL certificate for **machinename.example.edu**. Users can only authenticate when they use https://machinename.example.local, but this causes a certificate error.

The domain administrator confirms machinename.example.local is the Active Directory name, but not the DNS name, and says the mismatch can only be fixed at the application level. I believe machinename.example.local is the network name because it is what is returned when I ping localhost. How do I fix this mismatch?

Comment: "Users can only authenticate when they use https://machinename.example.local" is invalid. Windows authentication does not care which URL is used. What exactly is the site bindings set on IIS? You might run Binding Diagnostics to learn more, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: The site binding for 443 is Host name = "machinename", SSL certificate = "machinename.example.edu"

Comment: Then your host name setting is wrong. It should be either `machine.example.edu`, or empty. Please carefully read the report generated by Jexus Manager Binding Diagnostics, as it tells a lot on how a binding works.

Comment: I guess you would have to first tell me why I should be looking at site bindings for a problem authenticating with Active Directory.  For what it's worth I put in the FQDN in host name, reset, and there was no effect.

Comment: All users of your site, must type https://machinename.example.edu in their browsers. Then HTTPS requests will arrive on your machine, and processed by IIS where site bindings are the keys. That's the way to fix the certificate mismatch. If there are other problems once you address that, then you need to post a new question with enough details.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies within your question. When you have a certificate assigned to abc.com and if you are accessing the app using xyz.com, it will throw a certificate error. This is because the certificate was issued to xyz.com and not abc.com.

Now 2 ways in which you can fix this issue. Follow just one of the following.

1. Change your certificate and get a new one for xyz.com
2. Change bindings in IIS and assign abc.com within the hostname section.